# input number 11 decimals with pipe doesnt allow number > 999

Tags: html, angular, input, pipe, decimal

999.12345678901 works but anything >= 1000 evaluates to NaN (warning in console) and sets input to 0. I am using this Pipe in onBlur of input.

```
   @Pipe({
      name: 'rExact'
   })
   export class rExactPipe extends DecimalPipe {
        transform(value: number): any {
           if(isNaN(value))
               return null;

           return super.transform(value, "1.2-11");  
        }
  }
```

this is the onblur event:

```
this.selected.UnitPrice = +new rExactPipe(this.numberLocale).transform(this.selected.UnitPrice);
```

the input number field is binded like this: [(ngModel)]="selected.UnitPrice"

all numbers should work up to 15 digits float because JS is 64-bit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbctb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Post a complete minimal example, as I just did, but reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is DecimalPipe adds `,` symbol after thousands like here `1,000` and in your code this small plus here `+new` converts result back to number. this comma makes it unparsable, and, as a result you get NaN. to fix the issue for the view just remove the plus sign, and, if you need value, use it without pipe